# Creating a professional in app user interface in Android

Tags: android, user-interface, dynamic, fragment, state

Current situation:

We have different userinterfaces, which are build as fragments, for example the MenuFragment:

```
public class MenuFragment extends Fragment implements Hideable, View.OnClickListener {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      this.view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void hide() {
        view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    @Override
    public void show() {
        view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}
```

Hideable:

```
public static interface Hideable {

    void hide();

    void show();
}
```

States are enums:

```
public enum InterfaceState {
    STANDARD, TWO, THREE ;

    private List<Hideable> visibleElements;

    private void setVisibleElements(Hideable[] visibleElements) {
        this.visibleElements = Arrays.asList(visibleElements);
    }
}
```

Set them using:

```
InterfaceState.STANDARD.setVisibleElements(new Hideable[] { menuFragment });
```

where menuFragment is

```
menuFragment = (MenuFragment) activity.getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.menu_fragment);
```

Now i change the state calling changeToState:

```
public void changeToState(InterfaceState state) {

    List<Hideable> hideList = new LinkedList<>();
    for (Hideable e : this.currentState.visibleElements) {
        if (!state.visibleElements.contains(e))
            hideList.add(e);
            e.hide();

    }

    List<Hideable> showList = new LinkedList<>();
    for (Hideable e : state.visibleElements) {
        if (!this.currentState.visibleElements.contains(e))
            showList.add(e);
            e.show();
    }
```

The system seems to be buggy. Sometimes UI elements dont appear.

Questions:

1. Is this a good way to implement an UI? If not, what's a better way to do?
2. Does Android allocate space for a view, which has Visibility="GONE"? To use the upper mechanism, I need to define all UI elements (like MenuFragment menuFragment) directly on app start.
3. Any suggestions/improvements?

Thanks to all readers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. I always advocate the **convention over configuration** rule. Android has some nice conventions on how to design you user interface and you should s tick to them whenever possible.
2. No it does not. That is, `View.GONE` makes the view act as though it's not there (from the layouts point of view), where as `View.INVISIBLE` allocates the layout space needed for the view, but simply makes the view invisible. However, even with `View.GONE`, you'll still be able to get your view with `findViewById()`.
3. I think that storing information in an enum like that is bad idea. You should find a different method that suits you (either put your list in an activity, in the `Application` class or something similar.)

**EDIT:** You can find some usefull information about the pattern on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convention_over_configuration), and you can read more about the Android Design Guidelines [here](https://developer.android.com/design/index.html). There is also a nice document about the pattern [here](http://softwareengineering.vazexqi.com/files/convention_over_configuration.pdf). You can also look at AOSP's [code style guidelines](https://source.android.com/source/code-style.html) (or, well, rules) as they provide some nice conventions on how to write code.

Comment: Could you give me more informations about your first point? Where can I find literature?